# Storing HTML form values into an array in PHP and printing

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I am trying to get user input of 10 numbers in an html file that will be stored into an array on a php file.  Although when I try to print the array out all I am getting is the word "Array", any idea as to why?

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
</head>
<body>
Please enter 10 numbers that will be stored in an array:
<form action="practice3.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="number1[]" placeholder="First number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number2[]" placeholder="Second number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number3[]" placeholder="Third number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number4[]" placeholder="Fourth number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number5[]" placeholder="Fifth number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number6[]" placeholder="Sixth number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number7[]" placeholder="Seventh number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number8[]" placeholder="Eighth number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number9[]" placeholder="Ninth number"><br />
<input type="text" name="number10[]" placeholder="Tenth number"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php

    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    $number3 = $_POST['number3'];
    $number4 = $_POST['number4'];
    $number5 = $_POST['number5'];
    $number6 = $_POST['number6'];
    $number7 = $_POST['number7'];
    $number8 = $_POST['number8'];
    $number9 = $_POST['number9'];
    $number10 = $_POST['number10'];

    $myArray = Array($number1, $number2, $number3, $number4, $number5, $number6, $number7, $number8, $number9, $number10);

    echo $myArray;



?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

It will display information about your variable in a way that's readable by humans. can be used with arrays and objects.

Comment: That worked great, but why am I getting this? Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 9 ). I dont understand.  Is it saying  the first element of the first element of the array?  There are a lot of first elements in the line

Comment: use `echo '<pre>';`. It will be more readable. see the update.

Comment: Is this making an array within each element of the array? I am seeing two [0] for each number?

Comment: Yes it does because you are naming your inputs with `[]`. You have to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` will work but if you want control over formating you will need to [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over the array

```
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
   echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried it this way also. I am  getting the word "Array" 10 times in a row.  Closer, but the print_r way is working, but I would like control over the format

Comment: The update should now work once you remove `[]` from the HTML input names. I grabbed the wrong example from the PHP manual. I strongly suggest you read the PHP manual page I have linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate, echo expects a string and doesn't work for Arrays. In general when debugging people tend to use var_dump () which works on Objects, Arrays, Strings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the [] in your input names, number1, number2, ... will suffice. Then just use print_r to print the array.